# mPDF - When I import/merge PDFs with a fillable form field it strips the form elements

Tags: forms, pdf, mpdf

We're using mPDF, but when combining PDF files with Acrobat form fields, the output result strips the form fields.

[image: mPDF Form Fields Tripped]
I've combed through the documentation, looked extensively online, and I can't find a solution that works with mPDF.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: As of mPDF 7 you can create fillable forms within PDFs dynamically - :D !

Comment: I just stumbled over this answer (again). What has this feature to do with the fact that you cannot import PDFs with form fields in mPDF? I mean importing and creating are completely different things and for sure this answer is not the correct one for the initial question and misleading.

Answer (score 1):

mPDF uses FPDI in the back which simply does [not support importing of form fields](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-85).

Comment: Well, that answers that! Time to find another solution. Thanks.